# SilverStripe Images - How to get images with original dimensions?

Tags: image, silverstripe

I have a page which has Images in `many_many` relation.
How to get images with original dimensions?

I'm using below code

```
<code><% loop Images %>
$SetSize(250,250)
<% end_loop %></code>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<% loop Images %>
    $Me
<% end_loop %>
```

`$Me` is how you access the current item of the loop (it's a bit like `$this` in PHP).

Another way would be `$forTemplate`, but that's a bit inelegant.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Sorry for being late to thank you. :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. The `$Me` variable can be used outside of loops to simply be the getter for the current context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $URL and do something like

```
<img src="$URL" alt="$Title" />
```